# Underscore in regex not validating

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How do I add underscore as a part of my regex string.

Here is my string that checks for uppercase, lowercase, numbers and special characters. The rest of the special characters work. Validation isn't working for underscores.

```
 @"^[^\s](?=(.*[A-Za-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W]){1,})(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()-+=\[{\]};:<>|_.\\/?,\-`'""~]{1,})).*[^\s]$"
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at that regex, this certainly seems like one of those "two problems" affairs you get when solving things with regexes. Consider validating it through actual, readable code (involving multiple regexes, if you must) -- as a bonus this would also allow you to give an error message with details about the actual criteria not being matched.

Comment: Don't use regexes, you don't understand, they might match other things you don't want.

Answer (score 3):

This is the regex that AWS Cogito uses, it should apply to your situation:

```cs
@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\^$*.\[\]{}\(\)?\-“!@#%&\/,><’:;|_~`])\S{8,99}$"
```

You can check regexes at http://regexstorm.net, it's faster than building your application everytime.

Comment: Fixed formatting and URL in the meanwhile.

Comment: It was missing a backslash escape

Comment: Strange. It should work. Works fine on regexstorm.net and it matches the requirements. I've used it before already.

Comment: RegexStorm is a .NET regex tester. Give it a try ;)

Comment: It seems regexstorm is more forgiving than regex101. Just remove the backslash before  ```’``` and regex101 is happy too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've approached it like this: I took your requirements and made them into separate positive lookaheads:

Check for:

- uppercase `(?=.*[A-Z])`
- lowercase `(?=.*[a-z])` (note that I broke `A-Z` and `a-z` up into separate groups)
- numbers `(?=.*\d)`
- special characters `` (?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-+=\[{\]};:<>|_.\\/?,\-`'""~]) ``

You can then combine them in any order and I've combined them in the same order as I listed them above and anchored it with the beginning of the line using `^`. Don't add any extra matches before, in-between or after the groups in your requirement that could cause the regex to enforce a certain ordering of the groups:

- The lookahead for any non-word character `\W` makes it **impossible** to match `Underscore1_` since it will only match on *"anything other than a letter, digit or underscore"* - which is all `Underscore1_` contains.
- The starting `[^\s]` (and ending `[^\s]`) that consumes one character is likely destroying a lot of good matches. `Underscore1_` or `_1scoreUnder` shouldn't matter, but if you start with `_` and consume it with `[^\s]` like you do, the later lookahead for a special character will fail (unless you have a second special character in the password).

```cs
@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-+=\[{\]};:<>|_.\\/?,\-`'""~])"
```

If you have a minimum length requirement of, say, 7 characters, you just have to add `.{7,}$` to the end of the regex, making it:

```cs
@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()-+=\[{\]};:<>|_.\\/?,\-`'""~]).{7,}$"
```

Without a minimum length, a password of one character from each group will be enough, and since there are 4 groups, a password with only 4 characters will pass the filter.

I see no point in putting an upper length limit into the regex. If the user interface has accepted a string that is thousands of characters long, then why reject it for being too long later? The length of what you store is probably going to be much smaller anyway since you'll be storing the `bcrypt`/`scrypt`/`argon2`/`...` encoded password.

Suggestion: Also add space (or even whitespaces) to the list of special characters.

Answer (score 0):

In you regexp add underscore in 3rd Capturing Group [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eiUe7E/1)

```
@"^[^\s](?=(.*[A-Za-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W_]){1,})(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()-+=\[{\]};:<>|_.\\/?,\-`'""~]{1,})).*[^\s]$"
```

Comment: Then what use is that group? You could just remove it like I did in my answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo agree)

Comment: Also note that this will match `UNDERSCORE1_` which doesn't contain any lowercase letters, but it will not match `_Underscore1` which contains characters from all groups OP listed in the requirements.